# Running 32 bits compiled Visual Foxpro App in Win 7 64 bit machine

Tags: visual-foxpro

Good afternoon I have a inherited (from programmer abroad) Visual FoxPro 32 bits app and I have to make it run in a Windows 7 64 bits PC, once I try to run it it displays a message that says ("The version of this program is different from the version of windows you have") . I googled and installed VisualFoxPro 9 from Microsoft page and SP 2 for Visual Fox Pro, but it seems that as longs as the App was compiled in a 32 bits platform it can not run in a 64 bits Machine, any suggestions on that problem would be very appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Right-click the executable and choose `Troubleshoot compatibility`, and see if either `Try recommended settings` or `Troubleshoot program` will allow it to run.

Comment: You definitely can run VFP applications in 64-bit Windows. I do it all the time. I assume you're talking about an EXE built with VFP. Do you have the right runtime libraries available?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the correct runtimes installed. Do you know which version of VFP it was compiled in?

VFP comes in the following versions, each with their own runtimes:

- FPW 2.6a
- VFP 3
- VFP 5
- VFP 6
- VFP 7
- VFP 8
- VFP 9
- VFP 9 SP2

If you are sure that you have the correct runtime installed, are you sure it was built in Visual FoxPro and not the older FoxPro 2.X? That would be 16-bit and you would have some trouble running those versions.

Answer (score 0):

dear at first make right click on the setup or install file then go to the properties then compatibility tab and chose click on change settings for all users then select in the compatibility mode in the check box run this program in compatibility mode for select windows xp (service pack 2) and good luck its a tested and successful way